# JPG downloading Applet with JAVA

Tags: java, applet, jpeg

I'm trying to program an applet for users to download jpg files from an url by entering the list of links of jpg images. When I use the procedure in JCreator's compiler, it works well. However, when I put it into an applet, I could not handle. I'm giving the actionlistener part and the method of the program below. Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Action Listener:

```
class DownloadListener implements ActionListener 
  {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    String line = links.getText();
    String[] linkarray = line.split("\n");

    //int numOfLinks = linkarray.length;

    String directoryUser = directory.getText();

    try{
    downloadImg(linkarray, directoryUser);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    deneme.setText(ex.toString() + "Could not find file");

    }

  }                   
}
```

Method:

```
public void downloadImg(String[] linkarray, String directoryUser) throws IOException
{
    for(int i=0; i<linkarray.length; i++)
    {

        URL url = new URL(linkarray[i]);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
         out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        int j = 1;

        String address = directoryUser + "/" + "oda" + Integer.toString(j) + ".jpg";
        BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(address));

        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
        j++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Unsigned applets can't write to a local directory nor access other server. Does your applet have enough permissions?

Comment: I leraned that lately, so I've changed the program into application, however now I'm not able to embed it in my website.